# Facebook host my own photos

Tags: facebook

I have albums in Facebook and I 'd want them to put to my site. My own albums, not anyone else's.

I understand that I need an access token, and it works when I create one using Graph Explorer. However this expires.

Must I create a new application in order to manage my tokens myself? In that case, I have to submit notes to facebook to get approval for user_photos and user_videos permissions. Is that the case?

Comment: Are we talking about your personal profile, or a Facebook page? For the latter, you can create an extended page access token that has no default expiry; user tokens can be extended to be valid for up to two month only. But you do not need review for an app that is only used by yourself, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: It's the personal profile's albums